# JavaFX Chat Window like Facebook Chat

Tags: user-interface, javafx, window, chat

I have a question concerning my javafix application.

For some reasons i want to add a window to show error logs.

I would be a nice look if it is something similar to the facebook chat messenger window (see pictures).

So I want to add a window to my application with the following properties:

- when the title is clicked the window pops up
- when the title is clicked again the window is minimized

The content of the window will be realized with a list view.

But I don't have any idea to realize this window. Do you have some suggestions how to realize this issue?

Pictures:
(1) Chat minimized -> when clicking on it it pops up
[Chat minimized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0Ma6.png)

(2) Chat maximized -> when clicking on it it pops down
[Chat maximized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiVfU.png)

Comment: Can you be more specific about where you are stuck? Do you know how to create a window? How to show or hide a window? How to register event handlers to execute code when the user performs specific actions? Which particular step are you stuck on?

Comment: I am stuck in creating the window. It should be modal to the main window. In general I know how to create windows but when i hide them they are in the task bar. But I want this window like the chat window. This means modal to the main frame and when it is hidden it should appear similar to the chat window in the main frame.

Comment: The issue is how to add a modal frame to the main window which i can pop up and down like the facebook messenger.

The user interaction is clear for me

Comment: `Stage chatStage = new Stage();`, `chatStage.initOwner(mainStage);`, and `chatStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);`

Comment: https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/PopOver.html